# imageview does not move on touch event android

Tags: android, imageview

MY imageview does not move when ontouch event is called...Though I can see ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE happening from the log traces.

Here is my code:-

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motion) {



     float dy ;
     float dx;
     double r = 0;
     float angle = 0;

     switch(v.getId())
     {
        case R.id.arrow:
            switch(motion.getActionMasked())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In MOTION MOVE");
                    mX1 = motion.getX();
                    mY1 = motion.getY();
                    break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                  Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In MOTION UP");
                  mX2 = motion.getX();
                  mY2 = motion.getY();
                dy = -( mY2-mY1);
                dx = -(mX2-mX1);
                r = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                   angle = (int)Math.toDegrees(r);
                   updateRotation(angle);
                   break;

               default:
                   break;
            }

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of angle in ontouch: " + Double.toString(angle));

            break;

        default:
            break;
     }
    return true;
}
```

Basically I am trying to calculate the angular displacement when user touches the imageview and changes its position.

======================================
Edit:- Below is my update rotation function:-

```
public void updateRotation(double angle)

{

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow);
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    String filePath = null;
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value: " + Double.toString(angle));

    if(angle > 90)
        angle = 90;
    mtx.postRotate((float) angle);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
    Drawable draw =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);


    mImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
    }
```

=========================================================

Edit 2: Modified function

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motion) {



     float dy ;
     float dx;
     double r = 0;


     switch(v.getId())
     {
        case R.id.arrow:
            switch(motion.getActionMasked())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mX1 = motion.getX();
                mY1 = motion.getY();
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In MOTION MOVE");
                    mX1 = motion.getX();
                    mY1 = motion.getY();
                    break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                  Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In MOTION UP");
                  mX2 = motion.getX();
                  mY2 = motion.getY();
                dy = -( mY2-mY1);
                dx = -(mX2-mX1);
                r = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                   mAngle = (int)Math.toDegrees(r);
                   updateRotation();
                   break;

               default:
                   break;
            }

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of angle in ontouch: " + Float.toString(mAngle));

            break;

        default:
            break;
     }
    return true;
}
```

=============================================

Edit 3:- Strange thing is that if i modify my onTouch event and perform all the calculations in ACTION_MOVE the imageview responds for each touch event, but this is not what I want as I cannot do the proper angluar rotation in ACTION_MOVE event

Comment: what does `updateRotation()` do?

Comment: @Reno Added the function

Answer (score 1):

Ruchira,

From looking at your code and working with many onTouch innovations myself, I can tell you that the problem is definitely in your `onTouchEvent()`. You record the `mX1` and `mY1` in your `ACTION_MOVE` without recording the original `ACTION_DOWN` event. This means that every time you move your finger, the `onTouchEvent()` method thinks that this is the original position. Try this instead:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motion) {
     float dy ;
     float dx;
     double r = 0;
     float angle = 0;

     switch(v.getId())
     {
        case R.id.arrow:
            switch(motion.getActionMasked())
            {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mX1 = motion.getX();
                    mY1 = motion.getY();
                    break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In MOTION MOVE");
               //Just to support real time rotation, you could:
                    mX2 = motion.getX();
                    mY2 = motion.getY();
                    //... some rotation code.
                    break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In MOTION UP");
              // All of this should be fine.
                   mX2 = motion.getX();
                   mY2 = motion.getY();
                   dy = -( mY2-mY1);
                   dx = -(mX2-mX1);
                   r = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                   angle = (int)Math.toDegrees(r);
                   updateRotation(angle);
                   break;

               default:
                   break;
            }

            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of angle in ontouch: " + Double.toString(angle));

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That should at least track your numbers correctly, so that they may actually be used.

**Additional Considerations**
The most common mistake is to make sure that you have not set any of your tracking variables to final. If this is the case, the code will set it once, but not again...

When dealing with Drawables, it is important to get rid of the original Drawable and its callback. The reason for this is a well known issue that was never resolved in Android because a decision couldn't be made as to when exactly it was necessary and when it wasn't. Essentially, Android will eventually run out of memory, but will not necessarily tell you and just fail to update the image. This is how you do this (when replacing an image).

```
Drawable trash = mImageView.getBackgroundDrawable();
if (trash != null)
{   trash.setCallback(null);
    trash.recycle();
    trash = null;
}
mImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
```

Finally, you have to let the image know that it has to redraw itself. This isn't always the case, but is true more often than not. `mImageView.invalidate();` will often resolve the issue, and should be placed on the last line in your `updateRotation()` method.

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: I pasted the modified code but still the imageview is responding for the first time touch(rotates by 180) and subsequently does not rotate.

Comment: I have put the modified function  as part of my question in Edit2

Comment: your ACTION_MOVE still updates mX1 and mY1. Change it to update mX2 and mY2. ONLY your ACTION_DOWN should change mX1 and mY1.

Comment: .Thanks for pointing out the mistake.Now it rotates according to the logic given by me but only once.On the subsequent on touch the imageview does not respond.Why is this so?Am I missing some additional thing?

Comment: I can't tell for sure without seeing the whole class... but some things to look for are in my edit above. (Give it a few minutes to post)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to resolve my issue.I am sure it will do the needful.I am going to try all the approaches you suggested! Thanks a lot.And will update you with the result.

Comment: still it is not working.May be something needs to be changed in larger part of code.. So I am still looking at the issues...

Comment: my imageview is inside a horizontal scroll view.Van this cause any issue??

Comment: Yes, this can. Being in a Horizontal Scroll is not necessary at all if you have this code. It does help to streamline your code, but only if it handles all of the scrolling you want it to. Since it does not, the Horizontal Scroll is taking priority and Intercepting (as it is the Parent) when you ACTION_MOVE. I don't know how hard it would be to remove, but if it is easy, then I would simply get rid of it.

Comment: Actually, I rephrase, being in a Horizontal Scroll may not be necessary. It, of course, depends on what you are doing with it. What you can do is place additional code to read the state of whether you are rotating and hence avoid "scrolling" to nowhere by accident.

Comment: my game app requires a horizontal scroll view.. So can you please suggest some alternative approach?

Comment: No, it doesn't. That is just your preference. You can manually handle all of the scrolling if you want. (I don't recommend it though). Yes, there are several alternatives. You can actually move your Touch Handling to a Parent View that has access to the Scrolling and do you interruption in there, and then defer either to the ImageView or the Scroller depending upon what is going on. You might set an indicator to the app, like long pressing on the Image before rotation, and notifying the app and Scroller with an "isRotating" variable. What you are asking for is really another question though.

Comment: after carefully observation by clicking the image view multiple times, I observed that if the horizontal scroll view gets touched somehow imageview does not rotate but otherwise it rotates.IN the events when it does not rotate the ACTION_MOVE is called but the ACTION_UP is not called.so looks like it is horizontal scroll view's ontouch getting preference over imageview 's on touch event for failure scenarios.Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Drawable trash = mImageView.getBackgroundDrawable();
if (trash != null)
{   trash.setCallback(null);
    trash.recycle();
    trash = null;
}

This code gives me error as "The method recycle() is undefined for the type Drawable"

Comment: I apologize, you recycle Bitmaps... so if you can get the Bitmap from the Drawable (if (trash instanceof BitmapDrawable) ...) Then you can recycle it. Otherwise, just set the callback to null and you should be fine.